# Training a tf.keras model with a basic low-level TensorFlow training loop doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Note: All code for a self-contained example to reproduce my problem can be found below.

I have a `tf.keras.models.Model` instance and need to train it with a training loop written in the low-level TensorFlow API.

The problem:
Training the exact same tf.keras model once with a basic, standard low-level TensorFlow training loop and once with Keras' own `model.fit()` method produces very different results. I would like to find out what I'm doing wrong in my low-level TF training loop.

The model is a simple image classification model that I train on Caltech256 (link to tfrecords below).

With the low-level TensorFlow training loop, the training loss first decreases as it should, but then after just 1000 training steps, the loss plateaus and then starts increasing again:

[image]

Training the same model on the same dataset using the normal Keras training loop, on the other hand, works as expected:

[image]

What am I missing in my low-level TensorFlow training loop?

Here is the code to reproduce the problem (download the TFRecords with the link at the bottom):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import trange
import sys
import glob
import os

sess = tf.Session()
tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)

num_classes = 257
image_size = (224, 224, 3)

# Build a tf.data.Dataset from TFRecords.

tfrecord_directory = 'path/to/tfrecords/directory'

tfrecord_filennames = glob.glob(os.path.join(tfrecord_directory, '*.tfrecord'))

feature_schema = {'image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                  'filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                  'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tfrecord_filennames)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(tfrecord_filennames)) # Shuffle the TFRecord file names.
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda filename: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda single_example_proto: tf.parse_single_example(single_example_proto, feature_schema)) # Deserialize tf.Example objects.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda sample: (sample['image'], sample['label']))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda image, label: (tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3), label)) # Decode JPEG images.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda image, label: (tf.image.resize_image_with_pad(image, target_height=image_size[0], target_width=image_size[1]), label))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda image, label: (tf.image.per_image_standardization(image), label))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda image, label: (image, tf.one_hot(indices=label, depth=num_classes))) # Convert labels to one-hot format.
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(32)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
features, labels = iterator.get_next()

# Build a simple model.

input_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=image_size)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(input_tensor)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation=None, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_tensor, x)
```

This is the simple TensorFlow training loop:

```
# Build the training-relevant part of the graph.

model_output = model(features)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=tf.stop_gradient(labels), logits=model_output))

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

# The next block is for the metrics.
with tf.variable_scope('metrics') as scope:
    predictions_argmax = tf.argmax(model_output, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int64)
    labels_argmax = tf.argmax(labels, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int64)
    mean_loss_value, mean_loss_update_op = tf.metrics.mean(loss)
    acc_value, acc_update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels_argmax, predictions=predictions_argmax)
    local_metric_vars = tf.contrib.framework.get_variables(scope=scope, collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES)
    metrics_reset_op = tf.variables_initializer(var_list=local_metric_vars)

# Run the training

epochs = 3
steps_per_epoch = 1000

fetch_list = [mean_loss_value,
              acc_value,
              train_op,
              mean_loss_update_op,
              acc_update_op]

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

with sess.as_default():

    for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):

        tr = trange(steps_per_epoch, file=sys.stdout)
        tr.set_description('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, epochs))

        sess.run(metrics_reset_op)

        for train_step in tr:

            ret = sess.run(fetch_list, feed_dict={tf.keras.backend.learning_phase(): 1})

            tr.set_postfix(ordered_dict={'loss': ret[0],
                                         'accuracy': ret[1]})
```

Below is the standard Keras training loop, which works as expected. Note that the activation of the dense layer in the model above needs to be changed from `None` to 'softmax' in order for the Keras loop to work.

```
epochs = 3
steps_per_epoch = 1000

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(dataset,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch)
```

You can download the TFRecords for the Caltech256 dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_RzYK5iEuHHMYZqgpaVCqExvTSVseaJG) (about 850 MB).

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to solve the problem: Replacing the low-level TF loss function

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=tf.stop_gradient(labels), logits=model_output))
```

by its Keras equivalent

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(target=labels, output=model_output, from_logits=True))
```

does the trick. Now the low-level TensorFlow training loop behaves just like `model.fit()`.

This raises a new question:

What does `tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy()` do that `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2()` doesn't that leads the latter to perform much worse? (I know that the latter needs logits, not softmax output, so that's not the issue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing the low-level TF loss function

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=tf.stop_gradient(labels), logits=model_output))
```

by its Keras equivalent

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(target=labels, output=model_output, from_logits=True))
```

does the trick. Now the low-level TensorFlow training loop behaves just like `model.fit()`.

However, I don't know why this is. If anyone knows why `tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy()` behaves well while `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2()` doesn't work at all, please post an answer.

Another important note:

In order to train a `tf.keras` model with a low-level TF training loop and a `tf.data.Dataset` object, one generally shouldn't call the model on the iterator output. That is, one shouldn't do this:

```
model_output = model(features)
```

Instead, one should create a model in which the input layer is set to build on the iterator output instead of creating a placeholder, like so:

```
input_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=features)
```

This doesn't matter in this example, but it becomes relevant if any layers in the model have internal updates that need to be run during the training (e.g. BatchNormalization).

Answer (score 0):

You apply a softmax activation on your last layer

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
```

and you apply **again** a softmax when using 
`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` as it expects unscaled logits. From the documentation:

> WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax
>   on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the
>   output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.

Thus, remove the softmax activation of your last layer and it should work.

```
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation=None, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
[...]
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=tf.stop_gradient(labels), logits=model_output))
```

Comment: That's not the problem unfortunately. In my original post, before the tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2() function was commented out, I had activation=None in the Dense layer. Doing exactly that still led to the problem shown above.